Azure ML: Unable to find workspace
I would need help with an error message I get.
I'm using BICEP to create an ML Workspace.
I have this task:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Create Workspace
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnection)
      scriptType: 'bash'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        az extension add -n ml -y
        echo "RUNNING: az ml workspace create"
        az ml workspace create --name $(workspaceName) --location $(location) --resource-group $(resourceGroupName)

I have these logs:
RUNNING: az ml workspace create
The deployment request ***-1346692 was accepted. ARM deployment URI for reference: 
https://portal.azure.com//#blade/HubsExtension/DeploymentDetailsBlade/overview/id/%2Fsubscriptions%2F***%2FresourceGroups%2F***%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Resources%2Fdeployments%2F***
Creating Key Vault: (***951dec81  ) ..  Done (18s)
Creating Storage Account: (***52ffb00  )   Done (20s)
Creating Log Analytics Workspace: (***0e912b31  )  Done (16s)
ERROR: Code: UserError
Message: Unable to find workspace: /subscriptions/***/resourcegroups/***/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/***

I don't understand the error, I ask to create all required resources and the workspace and it says it doesn't find the workspace !!
Thanks

Based on your task definition, you are using the Azure CLI task to run the  az ml workspace create to create the Azure ML workspace in Azure Pipeline.
I can reproduce the same issue.

The cause of the issue is that the Azure ML workspace with the same name is in soft-delete state.
In this case, you are not able to create the Azure ML workspace with the same name.
To solve this issue, you need to navigate to Azure Portal -> Azure Machine Learning -> Recently deleted resources -> Select region and then you can hard delete the Azure ML resource.
For example:

Then you can re-run the Azure CLI to create the new Azure ML Workspace.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Manage soft deleted workspaces

Thanks. strangely, I see nothing in recently deleted, I guess it is because of my level of access rights, do you know if there is a specific role that would prevent me from seeing them ?

@ClaudeVernier you can check if you have selected the correct region of the deleted Azure ML? If you haven't selected any region, it will show empty result.

Yes, I saw that, I selected France-Central as I always use it in my script with that variable: location: 'francecentral', I'll check the documentation again to make sure the spelling is ok.  Thanks.
